# Include Path is overwriten by ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu, include-path

I got this little problem with PHP and Zend Framework.

I installed ZF using `apt-get install libzend-framework-php` which also install the binary `zf.sh` and the `zend-framework.ini` in `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`. I uncommented the line in the file which is:

```
[Zend]
include_path=${include_path} ":/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php"
```

The problem is that this overwrite totally my include_path. Usualy, it contains `/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`.

My include_path is now only: (from the phpinfo())

```
include_path    :/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php
```

You can see it at [this link](http://creationsmicroweb.com/?phpinfo).

I would like to know what's wrong because it's very annoying!

Comment: Have you tried adding the original include directories into the zend-framework.ini line?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it this way... I want to be able to add path one by one. Soon, I'll be adding ZF2 path and ZendX_ path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Zend include path to:

```
include_path=${include_path} ":/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear"
```

Comment: I would do that, but as I explained in my comment above, I want to be able to add path by adding a `.ini` file... Instead of editing the same many times...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, change your php.ini to: "include_path=".:/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear" and remove the line from the Zend config.